# Extend my LVM After Upgrading SSD

Tags: lvm, resize2fs

So, I have a 120 GB SSD (/dev/sdb) that I have a dual boot of Windows 7 and Fedora 17.  When I first started I only have a 60 GB SSD so my space was very limited.  I have a partition on my SSD (dev/sdb4) which I created with gparted, that shows a "Partition 5 LVM2" (dev/sdb5) below it which I believe is what the LVM is stored on(?).

Anyways, using gparted I extened my /dev/sdb4 to 27GB, which then created a "Free Space" of 17GB within /dev/sdb4.  Now I need to combine /dev/sdb5 and the free space into one.

I've tried: 
`lvextend -L+16G /dev/vg_mine/lv_root`
which results in:

```
Extending logical volume lv_root to 20.97 GiB
Insufficient free space: 512 extends needed, but only 0 available
```

I then used a `resize2fs /dev/vg_mine/lv_root` which results in:

`The filesystem is already 1302528 blocks long, nothing to do!`

Anybody point me in the right direction?  Am I on the right track so far?

Comment: Include fdisk output here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend your physical volume first, and then the logical volume:

```
pvresize /dev/sdb4
lvextend /dev/vg_mine/lv_root
```

Note that I've left off the `-L+16G` — this will use all free space.

Comment: Neither of these commands seemed to work for me:
pvresize /dev/sdb4
Failed to read physical volume "/dev/sdb4"
0 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized

lvextend /dev/vg_mine/lv_root
Please specify either size or extents but not both
Run `lvextend --help` for more information.

Comment: what's the output of "pvs" ? Can you dpaste it? Also, fwiw, with LVM you don't really need to resize partitions (not having to is one of the benefits of LVM) you could have just added the other partition to the volume group and then extended out that way.

Comment: Joel, that's what I think I'm trying to do.  Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: #pvs
/dev/sdb5 vb_mine lvm2 a-- 9.91G 0

Answer (score 1):

Is /dev/sdb5 still a different partition?  Then what you have to do is either repartition the space and combine /dev/sdb4 with /dev/sdb5.

Oh I assume nothing is in /dev/sdb5 that is important because you're its going to be destroyed in the process.

Another way, still destructive:

```
 - pvcreate /dev/sdb5
 - vgextend ..... /dev/sdb5
 - lvextend .....
 - then e2resize to resize the filesystem
```

Comment: Seems like my issues with this are coming from a mounted filesystem?

Comment: Well....yes, the filesystems on /dev/sdb5 have to be unmounted.  Again, they will be destroyed.